# DataframeのColumnのうちの一つがNaNになってしまう

Tags: python, dataframe

**やりたいこと**　　次のようなデータフレームのtitleのColumnからyearを抽出して別にyearのColumnを設けたい。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]**問題点**　　だが、以下のようなコードを試してみると警告が表示され、yearのColumnの値が全てNaNになってしまう。

```
def rm_dates_from_title(df: pd.DataFrame):
  df['year'] = df.title.str.extract('(\(\d\d\d\d\))', expand=False)

  df['year'] = df.year.str.extract('(\d\d\d\d)', expand=False)

  df['title'] = df.loc.title.str.replace('(\(\d\d\d\d\))', '', regex=True)

  rm_dates_from_title(recommended_movies)
recommended_movies.head(20)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 画像で見えている範囲では `title` に4桁の数字が含まれていませんので、`NaN` になるのはその通りだといえます。実際のところ、4桁の数字が含まれているタイトルはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: まずはWarningのメッセージにある通りに、locを使用する書き方に変更してはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

手元の環境は Pandas 1.5.2 ですが、以下の様に記述すると問題の `warning`(`SettingWithCopyWarning`)は表示されません(もっとも、質問に掲示されているコードでも表示されませんけれども)。 コメントにも書きましたが、`title` に括弧で囲まれた4桁の数字(映画の公開年)が含まれていない場合は `NaN` になります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
movieid,title,genres
50,"Usual Suspects, The",Crime|Mystery|Thriller
110,Braveheart,Action|Drama|War
260,Star Wars: Episode IV - New Hope(1977),Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
rx = r'\((\d{4})\)'
df['year'] = df['title'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
df['title'] = df['title'].str.replace(rx, '', regex=True)

print(df)
```

| movieid | title | genres | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | Usual Suspects, The | Crime|Mystery|Thriller | nan |
| 110 | Braveheart | Action|Drama|War | nan |
| 260 | Star Wars: Episode IV - New Hope | Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi | 1977 |